# getting error when trying to connect sharepoint 2013 port 80 from client machine

Tags: 2013, error

I installed SharePoint 2013 on a single server 2008 R2 with a built-in Sql server 2008 R2.
I created a new web application with a site collection on port 80, but when I want to open it from client machine it gives me error:Sorry, something went wrong.File Not Found. I am creating the root site collection using Publishing Portal template.

when I check the logs, I got these messages:

> An exception occurred while writing a service call usage entry.
>
> ...ty.GetCurrentThreadUserLogin(Boolean fFallbackToEnv)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPUsageManager.LogUsage(SPUsageEntry
>   usageEntry)

what do you think?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22153/discussion-on-question-by-forouz-getting-error-when-trying-to-connect-sharepoin).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So from your Error and other descriptions( as you are using the Publishing Portal.). I think your issue fall under the object cache settings. Please configure the Object cache on your web Application.

[Configure object cache user accounts in SharePoint Server 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff758656.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

As Alternative( or testing), you can create a team site and then test it, I am sure it will work.